# PHP-FPM seg faults, how do I find out why?

Tags: php, php-fpm, segmentation-fault

I have a Nginx running php through PHP-FPM.  When I do a phpinfo() the site shows up just fine but when i run my php code (which works fine on a VM that I have, this is an amazon EC2 instance) it seg faults.  The error message is not very descriptive.  Is there a way to find out WHY my code is causing php-fpm to seg fault?

This is the error from the php-fpm error.log

[12-May-2011 21:04:45] WARNING: [pool www] child 2447 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV) after 4026.581320 seconds from start
[12-May-2011 21:04:45] NOTICE: [pool www] child 2623 started

Answer (score 1):

You could try to find the line of code where php quits using XDebug.

Comment: Thank you! I never ended up trying this but i appreciate the feedback.  As it turns out I dropped the database that we had been using for session handling.  Instead of throwing a normal error this caused php-fpm to segfault!  I will tuck XDebug away for future use however!